# Using the search parameter on the /sites endpoint MSGraph .Net SDK

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph-sdks

I've been trying to build a query to return all SPO sites in a tenant using MSGraph. I can do this in the [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=sites?search=*&method=GET&version=v1.0) with the following query:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*
```

This [MSdocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/site-search?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csh) article seems to suggest that it's possible to use the search parameter but the C# example does not use search.

Has anyone been able to return all SPO sites in a tenant using the .Net SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using the following code to search for a site.

Add `search` as a query option in a request.

```
IGraphServiceClient client;
private async Task<Site> FindSiteAsync(string value)
{
    var siteQueryOptions = new List<QueryOption>()
    {
        new QueryOption("search", value)
    };
    var sites = await client.Sites.Request(siteQueryOptions).GetAsync();
    var site = sites.FirstOrDefault();
    return site;
}
```